# How much algebra is necessary to understand Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis"?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, self-learning

I've been reading up on the finite element method, and the text many people recommend is [The Mathematical Theory of Finite Element Methods by Brenner and Scott](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387759336). As part of the background, the authors recommend (vaguely) "a course in Real Analysis", and then they cite Rudin's "Real and Complex Analysis", Royden, and Folland. Since Ridgway Scott has stated a clear preference for "Big Rudin" (for instance, see [this review of Scott's numerical analysis book](http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/watkins/pdfiles/scott.pdf)), it is filtering to the top of my self-study list.

Poking around on Math.SE, I've seen a few people recommend studying abstract algebra before reading "Real and Complex Analysis". So my question is: how much abstract algebra is necessary to understand the first 15 chapters? (Of these, the first 9 or 10 are probably most important.) I ask because:

- I studied the first semester of algebra with Artin several years ago, so I remember (albeit vaguely) what a coset is, etc.
- I do computational mathematics and engineering with a heavy analysis bent, and thus rarely use abstract algebra
- Rudin's text seems to mostly mention ideals, which I've never covered formally, but...
- ...the one introductory functional analysis class (again, years ago) I took also mentioned ideals, and didn't seem to do anything particularly deep with them, beyond showing that other structures were ideals (or left ideals, or right ideals)

Comment: Sounds to me as if you know (more than enough) algebra to manage the algebra in Rudin. You can also digress to learn a little more as/if it becomes necessary.

Comment: You need very little algebra to understand RCA. You need some linear algebra (vector spaces, linear maps and determinants appear of course). It is good to know what rings are, $\mathbb{C}$-algebras, and  ideals, but except for the chapter about Banach algebras, that is not essential. Just go and start reading, and here or there you'll whip out an algebra book and refresh a topic.